# How to solve for the exponent in such a sum: $\sum_{j=0}^{b-1} f(n, k, b, j) \cdot g(n, k, j)^x = C$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, problem-solving

Suppose that $n, k, b \in \mathbf{N^\ast}$ are constants, $C \in \mathbf{R}_{>0}$ is also a constant, and that $f(n,k,b,j)$ and $g(n,k,j)$ are real valued functions.

Is there an algebraic way to solve 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{b-1} f(n, k, b, j) \cdot g(n, k, j)^x = C$$
for $x$, or only numerical methods can be used?

Comment: Take into account that $2^x+3^x=C$ does not show analytical solutions. So, only numerical methods could do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that then.